# How can create a SQL Profile use this SQL Tuning tool (SQLBooster)?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I got this SQL tuning tool from www.SQLFast.com

It looks fantastic! I used it analyze a very complex query (more than 1000 lines in a single SQL). It automatically analyzed the SQL and helped find out the root cause. I ever tuned such complex query, which took me 10+ hour for troubleshooting.

The question is, I cannot restructure this query. This tool declares it can reuse the tuned SQL outline data and create a SQL profile based on it. How can I do it? The example is not clear enough...

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the tuned SQL first, then go to the right-bottom (underneath the execution plan), click "Plan Outline", then click "Edit". Then you will be able to edit the outline data and apply the outline data to the selected SQL.